# Remove Metadata when Reading Data Frame from File in R

Tags: r, dataframe

**Problem:** How can we read a data file in R where the metadata at the start of the file is to be ignored?

In the example file below, we want to start reading to the end of the file from the line

```
1446.60     35785.0
```

**Example Excerpt**

```
Axis    Energy  Elements=   226

...

    Etch Time (EtchTime)\s  0.000000    
    Etch Level (EtchLevel)\ 0.000000    
Energy (E)  
eV  
1446.60     35785.0 
1446.80     34955.9 
1447.00     34448.0 
1447.20     33632.6 
1447.40     32905.1 
1447.60     31976.5 

...
```

Additionally, there is a space trailing the values in both columns, how can we get rid of them? Using `strip.white=T` does not seem to help:

```
read.table('myFile', sep = '\t', header = F, strip.white = T)
```

gives

```
        V1 V2          V3 V4
1   1446.6 NA  35785.0000 NA
2   1446.8 NA  34955.9000 NA
3   1447.0 NA  34448.0000 NA
4   1447.2 NA  33632.6000 NA
5   1447.4 NA  32905.1000 NA
```

Comment: You have a `skip` argument.

Comment: And if the number of lines of metadata is unknown ahead of time, you can first do something like `txt <- readLines('myFile'); read.table(text=txt, sep='\t', header=FALSE, skip=grep('^eV', txt))`.

Answer (score 1):

You could `pipe` with `awk` or `sed` to read from the lines starting with numbers (in linux).

```
 read.table(pipe("awk '/^\\s*(-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]*)?\\s*)+$/ {print $0}' Nyxynyx.txt"),
         header=FALSE)
 #     V1      V2
 #1 1446.6 35785.0
 #2 1446.8 34955.9
 #3 1447.0 34448.0
 #4 1447.2 33632.6
 #5 1447.4 32905.1
 #6 1447.6 31976.5
```

NOTE:  `Nyxynyx.txt` is the file